# JAVA_HOME on win 2008 server points to different places from different calles

Tags: java, php, windows-server-2008, environment-variables, java-home

my problem is with JAVA_HOME variable. When i echo it inside cmd, it points to jdk as it should, when i echo it from powershell, it points to jre7 and when i echo it with php script from web it points jre6. I have tried to set it with set JAVA_HOME and set-variable JAVA_HOME from both the powershell and php script which i called from web and neither did work. Does anybody have some idea how could i fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually solve the problem, I just cured the symptoms. I have edited the ant.bat. Just added the line: set JAVA_HOME=path\to\jdk at the start of the file

Answer (score 2):

is it possible JAVA_HOME is defined as a user variable and not a system variable and those processes are running as different users ?

Comment: it is defined as system variable, i first have set it throught System->Advanced System Settings->Environment Variables->System Variables

Comment: and no other user in the system has JAVA_HOME defined as a user var that could interfere ?
how about funny games with the %PATH% variable ?

Comment: i have checked registers and in user variables there are only tmp and temp defined and system PATH does not have any trace of jre6 or jre7... i don't get it... it is like some kind of black magic